# Multiple Select form with php ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hi there i having trouble on php ajax to show the result in select field. What i want is when i choose the option in select field, it should load the ajax php and show up the second select field, then i select an option in second select field, then it should also load the ajax php and show up the third select field. But i'm failed to load the third select field, is there any mistake i had done in my code? Sorry that i'm still new to ajax php.

Here is my php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>MIHRM Customer Information System</title>
<script>
        function showUser(str) {
          if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return;
          }
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
              document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser1.php?q="+str,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function showUser1(str1) {
          if (str1=="") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML="";
            return;
          }
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
              document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser1-1.php?z="+str1,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>

    </head>
<div class="rightpanel">

            <ul class="breadcrumbs">
                <li><a href="dashboard.html"><i class="iconfa-home"></i></a> <span class="separator"></span></li>
                <li><a href="">Generate Excel Report</a> <span class="separator"></span></li>
                <li>List by Position & State</li>
            </ul>

            <div class="pageheader">
                <!--
                <form action="results.html" method="post" class="searchbar">
                    <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="To search type and hit enter..." />
                </form>
                -->
                <div class="pageicon"><span class="iconfa-pencil"></span></div>
                <div class="pagetitle">
                    <h5>Generate Excel</h5>
                    <h1>Generate List of Contact by Position & State</h1>
                </div>
            </div><!--pageheader-->

            <div class="maincontent">
                <div class="maincontentinner">


                <div class="widgetbox box-inverse">
                    <h4 class="widgettitle">Contact List by State</h4>
                    <div class="widgetcontent wc1">
                        <form id="form1" class="stdform" method="post" action="$phpself" >
                                <br/>

                                <div class="control-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="typeOfUser">Type of Data</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><text style="color:#D84A38;font-size:20px">* </text>
                                    <select name="typeOfUser" id="typeOfUser" class="required" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
                                    <option value="">Choose One</option>
                                    <option value="client">Client</option>
                                    <option value="prospects">Prospects</option>
                                </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                 <div id = "txtHint"></div>

                                 <div id = "txtHint1"></div>

                                <p class="stdformbutton">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Generate Report</button>
                                </p>
                        </form>
                    </div><!--widgetcontent-->
                </div><!--widget-->
                .....
```

getuser1.php code here:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','csci311');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT distinct position FROM $q";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


echo '<div class="control-group">';
echo '<label class="control-label" for="position">Available position</label>';
echo '<div class="controls"><text style="color:#D84A38;font-size:20px">* </text>';
echo '<select name="position" id="position" class="input-large" onChange="showUser1()>';
echo '<option value="">Choose One</option>';
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row["position"].'">'.$row["position"].'</option>';
            }
        echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

getuser1-1.php code here:

```
<?php

    $z = $_GET['z'];

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','csci311');
    if (!$con) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
    $sql="SELECT distinct state FROM $z";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


    echo '<div class="control-group">';
    echo '<label class="control-label" for="state">Available State</label>';
    echo '<div class="controls"><text style="color:#D84A38;font-size:20px">* </text>';
    echo '<select name="state" id="state" class="input-large" >';
    echo '<option value="">Choose One</option>';
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$row["state"].'">'.$row["state"].'</option>';
                }
            echo '</select>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';



    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: you should use the developer console to see if your ajax is being returned, then you can see if you have a problem w/ your ajax or your php.

Comment: @dgig Hi there, what do you mean by developer console? Sorry i was still new here

Comment: in your browser, there are developer tools that you can use to watch the network activity. when you make an ajax call, you'll see it appear in the "network" list and you can view the response. If there is no ajax call happening at all, you have a problem w/ your javascript. If the response comes back, then you can see if maybe you have a PHP error. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/part1/

Answer (score 0):

On your echo statements, before each " put a \ in front of it. So it shows \".

" is a reserved character in PHP so for PHP to know you want it to be part of a string you have to place a \ in front of it.

Another way to deal with this issue would be to swap where you use single and double quotes. Use the single quotes in the HTML and the double quotes for the PHP.

I would also recommend getting a good quality IDE. I use Netbeans. There are many other good ones out there. You can place this code in any decent IDE and it will tell you what the problem is.

```
echo '<div class=\"control-group\">';
echo '<label class=\"control-label\" for=\"position\">Available position</label>';
echo '<div class=\"controls\"><text style=\"color:#D84A38;font-size:20px\">* </text>';
echo '<select name=\"position\" id=\"position\" class=\"input-large\" onChange=\"showUser1()>';
echo '<option value=\"\">Choose One</option>';
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value=\"'.$row["position"].'\">'.$row["position"].'</option>';
            }
        echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```